# Get upcoming Saturday from the list of dates

Tags: excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I want to get the upcoming saturday with reference to current system date.
The formula should give June 5 when the system date is May 29 till June 4, when the system date is June 5 it would return the next upcomin Satuday

This formula returns all matching dates, but I need a single upcoming date as a result and not a range result.

```
=iferror(ARRAYFORMULA(if(A2:A>today(),A2:A, 0/0)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This formula will return the next saturday, even if today IS a saturday

```
=TODAY()+(7-WEEKDAY(TODAY()))+(7*(7=WEEKDAY(TODAY())))
```

Replace TODAY() with a reference to a cell to use a different date